# Python Selenium Dynamic table cell returning empty string

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get value from a dynamic loading table, when I click on the TD element it works all ok.
But when I am tryin to get the text from same TD , it is returning empity string.
I have tried  XPATH, CSS_Selector

Below is the UI look, I want to get the amount
[image]

Below is the HTML Snap
[image]

> ```
> amount = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Table_Cheque_Ref_Details"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]').click
> ```

Working Fine

> ```
> amount=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Table_Cheque_Ref_Details"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]').text
> print amount
> ```

returns empity string

> amount = WebDriverWait(driver,
>   10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,
>   '//*[@id="xfe38"]'), '0')) print amount

Timeout Exception

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_id('amount').get_attribute('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

As @Andersson already mentioned, you can use `get_attribute('value')` to extract the text from input field. Let's create the following example:

```
driver.get('http://demo.automationtesting.in/Register.html') # get sample page
time.sleep(3) # pause to wait until page loads

input_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='basicBootstrapForm']/div[4]/div/input") # phone input field
input_el.click()
input_el.send_keys("123")

print(input_el.text) # prints nothing
print(input_el.get_attribute("value")) # prints '123'
```

---

## Analysis

If we go to the dev tools:

[image: img]

we will see the following HTML for our `input`:

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-valid-required ng-invalid-pattern" ng-model="Phone" required="" pattern="^\d{10}$">
```

it does not have any text in the tag, that's why calling

```
print(input_el.text)
```

will print nothing. If the HTML would look like:

```
<label class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Email address*</label>
```

then

```
print(label_el.text)
```

would print the text inside `label` tag - `Email address*`.

Comment: Thank you both ,@Andersson an @Andrei Suvorkov, I have extended the XPATH and got attribute Value.         -   amount=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Table_Cheque_Ref_Details"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]/div/input').get_attribute('value')

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't have the value attribute as well but it's printing the value, why ?

Comment: That's a good question! You can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815802/where-input-value-will-be-saved/51815858#51815858